# Cannot automate with cron the changing of the configuration with dconf on Debian (it worked on Ubuntu)?

Tags: debian, cron, dconf, antix

This script worked in adjusting the background color and the font color in `gnome-terminal` when run from cron on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

detect_dstr() {
  distribution=$(grep -E '^ID=' /etc/os-release | awk -v FS='=' '{print $2}')
    
    if [ "$distribution" == "debian" ]; then
        echo "debian"
    elif [ "$distribution" == "ubuntu" ]; then
        echo "ubuntu."
    else
        echo "unknown"
    fi 
}

chng_t_drk() {
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-color "'#000000'"
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/foreground-color "'#ffffff'"
}
chng_t_lght() {

}

h=$(date +%-H) 
if [[ "$h" -gt 16 ]]; then chng_t_drk
elif [[ "$h" -gt 4 &&  "$h" -lt 16 ]]; then chng_t_lght; fi
unset h
```

I am now on a [Debian-stable-based distribution](https://antixlinux.com/) that utilizes `sysvinit` and this script no longer works from cron. The theme changes when I manually execute it, though. Even specifying the display
does not help:
`*/10 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 ~/gnome-terminal/change-theme.sh`
I checked with `dconf-editor` and the ID is the same on Ubuntu 22.04, Debian Testing(trixie) and on Antix (based on Debian Stable). Why is it then that I cannot automate of changing the configuration on the latter two distros?

Answer (score 0):

Let's add a bit to your script:

- Let's tell cron which shell needs to be running to run the script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), most likely `/bin/bash`.  The first line of any script should always be the shebang, written as `#!/bin/bash`.
- You need to make the script executable with a `sudo chmod +x` from the terminal.

I don't believe you need to specify the `DISPLAY`.

Per your comment, let's start debugging `cron`s behavior:

- Are there other working jobs in cron right now?
- If not, let's test for sanity with some debugging cron jobs:

```
#Identify what in the path variable in the context of your script
* * * * * echo $PATH > ~/gnome-terminal/cron.log

#Identify the shell being use in your script
* * * * * echo $SHELL > ~/gnome-terminal/cron.log

#Identify the working directory your cron job natively executes in
* * * * * echo $PATH > ~/cron.log
```

Make sure that `$SHELL` and both `$PATH`'s match.  Inspect each log with a text editor or `cat`.

**Question**: Do you have a user `crontab`, or was this the default one?

Comment: The shebang was there all the time. I did forget to mention it in the question - I modified it in response to your comment.